# setTimeout return false on submit button click

Tags: jquery

I have a code like this for the submit button `button[type='submit]` of a form:

```
$('#submitButtonId').click(function () {
    setTimeout(function() { return false; }, 100);
});
```

But the submitting of the form still continues. **How can I stop the submitting of the form by `return false` with a time delay on the `click` event of the submit button?**

We need the time delay for some UI purposes. Is there a different approach to achieve this?

I am using jQuery v1.11.0 for a modern (up-to-date) browser.

Comment: You want to stop the form's default event, but only after 100ms? You're a tease!

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: You are returning `false` from the timeout callback function, not the click handler function. That is why you aren't seeing what you expect.

Comment: lol @scrowler...I think what he actually wants is to delay the form submission...can you confirm that mate?

Comment: @Leo Not actually, the `return false` would be replaced with a `formvalidator` function that will return `isValid` if the form is valid. I need to delay it since I just reuse the `focusout` event of the required form fields that has a delay and set `$(this).data('isValid')`. I will post the complete code if you require more context.

Comment: @JohnIsaiahCarmona nope, that's cool! Point made! Your question was misleading me a bit without more context...no code needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not knowing the context of this UI change, I would suggest you use e.preventDefault() first

```
e.g.
$('#submitButtonId').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $form.submit();
        return false;
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: Will this submit the form when I `return true`?

Comment: @JohnIsaiahCarmona no, this will not submit your form...you'll have to manually submit it

Comment: Use `$(this).submit()` when you want to submit it later. If you do that inside a callback (timeout function) you'll need to pass the reference in, e.g. `var $form = $(this);` then inside your setTimeout callback use `$form.submit()`

Comment: @MichaelOtte..can you please update your answer so I can upvote it? Otherwise, I'll have to add one answer myself ;)

Comment: +1 @MichaelOtte cheers! It was more about providing the complete correct answer...for posterity ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want call click function after 100 miliseconds and check click or cancel.You can try

```
$('#submitButtonId').click(function () {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function() {clickbutton() }, 100);
});
 function clickbutton()
{
 //  if(conditionok)submit();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you also need to prevent the default form action as the other answer mentions otherwise your form will be submitted before your javascript has time to react.